# get text from textview .. by id that set programmatically

Tags: android

I have 3 **TextView** objects, that I created programmatically

Every **TextView** was repeated 7 times and **ontouchlistener** for the layer that contain them.

When **onTouch** on the layer, I want to **gettext** from one of the **TextView** by the same view **Id**

I already tried ..

```
    //tvDay is the one i want to get it text
    tvDay.findViewById(v.getId());
    String course = tvDay.getText().toString();
```

Comment: `tvDay = findViewById(v.getId());` ?

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter from the `onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)` method should be your containing layer.

From this view you should be able to call `findViewById()` and pass the id of the TextView that you created. Just like in Sherifs comment:

`tvDay = findViewById(v.getId());`

Just another note (from what I know):
When you created the `TextView`s programmatically you have to set an `id` for the each single `TextView` yourself (to be able to reference them in the `findViewById()` method).

Answer (score 0):

You should set onTouchListeners for your TextViews and not for the container.